# Object doesn't implement IField

Tags: python, plone, zope, archetypes

I have following piece of code to patch the Folder:

```
ATFolderSchema = ATContentTypeSchema.copy() + \
    ConstrainTypesMixinSchema.copy() + NextPreviousAwareSchema.copy()
finalizeATCTSchema(ATFolderSchema, folderish=True, moveDiscussion=False)

field =  StringField("rafal_shortdescription",
            schemata = "default",
            widget = StringWidget(
                label = _(u"label_shortdescription",
                    default=u"Short Description"),
                description = _(u"help_shortdescription",
                    default=u"Used in tabs."),
                ),
            ),

ATFolderSchema.addField(field)
```

and last line throws:

```
 File "/home/rafal/projects/vidensportalen_v2/eggs/Products.Archetypes-1.6.4-py2.6.egg/Products/Archetypes/Schema/__init__.py", line 198, in _validateOnAdd
    raise ValueError, "Object doesn't implement IField: %r" % field
zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/home/rafal/projects/vidensportalen_v2/parts/instance/etc/site.zcml", line 12.2-12.39
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/home/rafal/projects/vidensportalen_v2/eggs/Plone-4.0.2-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/meta.zcml", line 39.4-43.10
    ValueError: Object doesn't implement IField: <Field rafal_shortdescription(string:rw)>
```

Any idea why?

Comment: It would probably help if you showed us where you'd imported StringField from...  Otherwise we can't know if the object _does_ implement IField.

Comment: Why don't use archetypes.schemaextender?

Comment: memoryleaks - for now we have code with schemaextender, but it is leaking. anyway, please stick with 'patching' version of question :)

Comment: Did you report this to the schemaextender authors?

Comment: There were two problems, first - use of finalize in wrong place - befor adding field. Second, I shoudnt use finalizeSchema but generateMethods.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd advise you to use [archetypes.schemaextender](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/archetypes.schemaextender) instead of using patches to alter Archetypes content types.

The package includes documentation on how to implement your additional field.

As for your error, you created a tuple with one element, a field:

```
>>> example = 1,
>>> print example
(1,)
```

Delete the trailing comma and your code should work as intended.

Comment: I am removing schemaextender from my code - due to the memory leaks.

Comment: And this is reason why I have to make it now by monkeypatch :)

Comment: I answered both your question and gave you advise. Was the answer incorrect and thus worth a -1 vote?

Comment: Hi Martijn, yes you are right. I put -1 to highlight that answer was not helpful for me, but probably was not fair for you. Gave it back now, and thanks for the effort!

Comment: Ach, yes, now I cannot it give back until answer will be edited.